# Basis for sum of all extensions of a completion: $\bigoplus_{w \mid v} \mathcal{O}_{w}$ over $\mathcal{O}_{v}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was going over notes from a class and it was stated (without proof) that if $\xi_{1}, \ldots, \xi_{n}$ is a basis of $K/k$, then for almost all places $v$, $\xi_{1}, \ldots, \xi_{n}$ is a basis for $\bigoplus_{w \mid v} \mathcal{O}_{w}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_{v}$ module.  I'm sure there are references out there, but I haven't been able to find one.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could either help me out with a proof or a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the statement that a torsion module over a Dedekind domain localizes to zero at all but finitely many primes.

Concretely, let $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\mathcal{O}_k$. Then the matrix $A$ such that $(u_1, \dots, u_n) = (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \cdot A$ has entries in $K$ and non-zero determinant. Hence there is a finite set of primes $S$ such that both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have entries which are integral at all primes outside $S$; and it follows that $(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$ is a basis of $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathcal{O}_{k, v}$ over $\mathcal{O}_{k, v}$ for all $v \notin S$.

EDIT: More precisely, the determinant argument shows that there is a finite set of primes $S$ such that the set $\{ \xi_1 \otimes 1, \dots, \xi_n \otimes 1\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathcal{O}_k[1/S]$ over $\mathcal{O}_k[1/S]$. Since $\mathcal{O}_{k, v}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_k[1/S]$-algebra for any $v \notin S$ this implies that $\{ \xi_1 \otimes 1, \dots, \xi_n \otimes 1\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathcal{O}_{k, v}$ over $\mathcal{O}_{k, v}$ for any $v \notin S$.

Comment: I feel like I have a small sticking point.  For example, over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, if I had $\frac{3}{7}\xi_{1} \otimes \frac{25}{11}$, then I want this to come from $\frac{25}{3\cdot11}(3\xi_{1} \otimes 1)$.  But I don't think I can pass the $11$ out since the tensor is taken over $\mathcal{O}_{k}$, so elements of $\mathcal{O}_{k,v}$ can't pass from the first coordinate to the second.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking here. What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: So what has been shown is that there is a finite set of primes where $\{\xi_{1}, \cdots, \xi_{n}\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ over $\mathcal{O}_{k,v}$, correct? But the tensor is over $\mathcal{O}_{k}$, so I wasn't sure that the $\mathcal{O}_{k,v}$ could act on the first part of the tensor.  I could be totally off base.

Comment: I've added some more explanation -- hope that clears up your question.